# sklearn Crossvalidation with GridSearch

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

The question is: when I do the fit with a GridSearch, I need to do something to have a crossvalidation process?

Thing that I know:

1.- I can set a scoring function (But is not so clear how to do that, at least to me)

2.- If I do not pass a 'cv' param to the GridSearch class then it  use the default 3-fold cross validation.

What exactly do GridSearch with the data that I pass?, all data is used in the train or is splitted inside in a train and test data?

Thanks!

PD: seems that my classifier have overfitting because have a score of 100% but do not have good results with new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [GridSearchCV documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV). It describes everything you want in detail.

GridSearch will train the given estimator over all given parameters values and finds the parameters which give the highest (or lowest, if a loss function is used) score on the train data.

`GridSearchCV` will do the same thing with Cross-validation internally. Parameters for estimators can be supplied in `GridSearchCV` with `param_grid` argument.

For your queries:

1. **Scoring** - You can pass any string available [on this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) (depending on your classifier). Or you can pass your own custom scorer with [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer).
2. **CV** - Same for cv. Either you can pass a number for that many folds cross-validation, or a cv object. You can check available cv iterators at [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators).